# Problem when updating a table using celery task: OperationalError

Tags: django, django-celery, celery-task

**EDIT 2022-10-04 18:40**

I've tried using bulk_update and bulk_create as these method only query database once but still have the same issue

would appreciate any help/explanation on this issue

```
'''
    Task to edit data correction forms (DCF) online
'''
@shared_task(bind=True)
def DCF_edition(self):
    
    print(timezone.now())

    DCF_BEFORE_UPDATE = pd.DataFrame.from_records(DataCorrectionForm.objects.all().values())
    
    if not DCF_BEFORE_UPDATE.empty :
        DCF_BEFORE_UPDATE = DCF_BEFORE_UPDATE.rename(columns={"patient": "pat"})
        DCF_BEFORE_UPDATE = DCF_BEFORE_UPDATE.astype({'record_date': str,'created_date': str}) 
        DCF_BEFORE_UPDATE['dcf_status'] = DCF_BEFORE_UPDATE.apply(lambda status: 0, axis=1)
    
    # list of dataframe to concat
    data = []
    
    # load queries definition
    queries = queries_definitions()
    # print(queries)
    if not queries.empty:
        for index, row in queries.iterrows():
            print('Query ide',row['ide'])
            # print(row['ide'],row['query_type'],row['crf_name'].lower(),row['crf identification date'],row['variable_name'],row['variable_label'],row['query_condition'],row['fields_to_display'])
            try:
                missing_or_inconsistent =  missing_or_inconsistent_data(row['ide'],row['query_type'],row['crf_name'].lower(),row['crf identification date'],row['variable_name'],row['variable_label'],row['query_condition'],row['fields_to_display']) #.iloc[:10] #to limit rows
                missing_or_inconsistent.columns.values[2] = 'record_date' # rename the date column (that have database name)
                missing_or_inconsistent['dcf_ide'] = str(row['ide']) + '_' + row['variable_name'] + '_' + missing_or_inconsistent[row['crf primary key']].astype(str)
                missing_or_inconsistent['category'] = row['query_type']
                missing_or_inconsistent['crf'] = row['crf_name']
                missing_or_inconsistent['crf_ide'] = missing_or_inconsistent[row['crf primary key']]
                missing_or_inconsistent['field_name'] = row['variable_name']
                missing_or_inconsistent['field_label'] = row['variable_label']
                missing_or_inconsistent['field_value'] = missing_or_inconsistent[row['variable_name']]
                missing_or_inconsistent['message'] = row['query_message']
                missing_or_inconsistent['query_id'] = 'Query ide ' + str(row['ide'])
                missing_or_inconsistent['dcf_status'] = 1
                missing_or_inconsistent['created_date'] = timezone.now()
                missing_or_inconsistent['deactivated'] = False
                missing_or_inconsistent['comments'] = None
                data.append(missing_or_inconsistent[['ide','dcf_ide','category','crf','crf_ide','pat','record_date','field_name','field_label','message','field_value','dcf_status','created_date','query_id','deactivated','comments']])

                dcf = pd.concat(data)

            except Exception as e:
                Log.objects.create(dcf_edition_status=0,dcf_edition_exception=str(e)[:200])
                continue       
        
        DCF_AFTER_UPDATE = pd.concat([DCF_BEFORE_UPDATE,dcf])
        DCF_AFTER_UPDATE['duplicate'] = DCF_AFTER_UPDATE.duplicated(subset=['dcf_ide'],keep='last')
        DCF_AFTER_UPDATE['dcf_status'] = DCF_AFTER_UPDATE.apply(lambda row: 2 if row['duplicate'] else row['dcf_status'],axis=1)
        DCF_AFTER_UPDATE = DCF_AFTER_UPDATE.drop_duplicates(subset=['dcf_ide'],keep='first').drop(columns=['duplicate'])
        DCF_AFTER_UPDATE.rename(columns = {'pat':'patient',}, inplace = True)
        # Cast date into string format to be able to dumps data
        DCF_AFTER_UPDATE = DCF_AFTER_UPDATE.astype({'record_date': str}) if not DCF_AFTER_UPDATE.empty else DCF_AFTER_UPDATE

        records_to_update = [
            DataCorrectionForm(
                    ide=record['ide'],
                    dcf_ide=record['dcf_ide'],
                    category=record['category'],
                    crf=record['crf'],
                    crf_ide=record['crf_ide'],
                    patient=record['patient'],
                    record_date=record['record_date'],
                    field_name=record['field_name'],
                    field_label=record['field_label'],
                    message=record['message'],
                    field_value=record['field_value'],
                    dcf_status=record['dcf_status'],
                    created_date=record['created_date'],
                    query_id=record['query_id'],
                    deactivated=record['deactivated'],
                    comments=record['comments']
            ) for i, record in DCF_AFTER_UPDATE[(DCF_AFTER_UPDATE['dcf_status'] != 1)].iterrows()
        ]
        if records_to_update:
            DataCorrectionForm.objects.bulk_update(records_to_update,['dcf_status'])

        records_to_create = [
            DataCorrectionForm(
                    dcf_ide=record['dcf_ide'],
                    category=record['category'],
                    crf=record['crf'],
                    crf_ide=record['crf_ide'],
                    patient=record['patient'],
                    record_date=record['record_date'],
                    field_name=record['field_name'],
                    field_label=record['field_label'],
                    message=record['message'],
                    field_value=record['field_value'],
                    dcf_status=record['dcf_status'],
                    created_date=record['created_date'],
                    query_id=record['query_id'],
                    deactivated=record['deactivated'],
                    comments=record['comments']
            ) for i, record in DCF_AFTER_UPDATE[(DCF_AFTER_UPDATE['dcf_status'] == 1)].iterrows()
        ]
        if records_to_create:
            DataCorrectionForm.objects.bulk_create(records_to_create)
```

---

**EDIT 2022-10-04 13:40**

I've tried to "optimized" code using update_or_create() method but doesn't change anything

I still have an OperationalError with the line `DataCorrectionForm.objects.update_or_create(...)`

How can I update my database?

```
'''
    Task to edit data correction forms (DCF) online
'''
@shared_task(bind=True)
def DCF_edition(self):
    
    DCF_BEFORE_UPDATE = pd.DataFrame.from_records(DataCorrectionForm.objects.all().values())

    if not DCF_BEFORE_UPDATE.empty :
        DCF_BEFORE_UPDATE.drop(columns=['ide'])
        DCF_BEFORE_UPDATE = DCF_BEFORE_UPDATE.rename(columns={"patient": "pat"})
        DCF_BEFORE_UPDATE = DCF_BEFORE_UPDATE.astype({'record_date': str,'created_date': str}) 
        DCF_BEFORE_UPDATE['dcf_status'] = DCF_BEFORE_UPDATE.apply(lambda status: 0, axis=1)
    
    # list of dataframe to concat
    data = []
    
    # load queries definition
    queries = queries_definitions()
    if not queries.empty:
        for index, row in queries.iterrows()       
            try:
                missing_or_inconsistent =  missing_or_inconsistent_data(row['ide'],row['query_type'],row['crf_name'].lower(),row['crf identification date'],row['variable_name'],row['variable_label'],row['query_condition'],row['fields_to_display']) #.iloc[:10] #to limit rows
                missing_or_inconsistent.columns.values[2] = 'record_date' # rename the date column (that have database name)
                missing_or_inconsistent['dcf_ide'] = str(row['ide']) + '_' + row['variable_name'] + '_' + missing_or_inconsistent[row['crf primary key']].astype(str)
                missing_or_inconsistent['category'] = row['query_type']
                missing_or_inconsistent['crf'] = row['crf_name']
                missing_or_inconsistent['crf_ide'] = missing_or_inconsistent[row['crf primary key']]
                missing_or_inconsistent['field_name'] = row['variable_name']
                missing_or_inconsistent['field_label'] = row['variable_label']
                missing_or_inconsistent['field_value'] = missing_or_inconsistent[row['variable_name']]
                missing_or_inconsistent['message'] = row['query_message']
                missing_or_inconsistent['DEF'] = 'Query ide ' + str(row['ide'])
                missing_or_inconsistent['dcf_status'] = 1
                missing_or_inconsistent['created_date'] = timezone.now()
                missing_or_inconsistent['deactivated'] = False
                missing_or_inconsistent['comments'] = None
                data.append(missing_or_inconsistent[['dcf_ide','category','crf','crf_ide','pat','record_date','field_name','field_label','message','field_value','dcf_status','created_date','DEF','deactivated','comments']])

                dcf = pd.concat(data)

            except Exception as e:
                Log.objects.create(dcf_edition_status=0,dcf_edition_exception=str(e)[:200])
                continue       
        
        DCF_AFTER_UPDATE = pd.concat([DCF_BEFORE_UPDATE,dcf])
        DCF_AFTER_UPDATE['duplicate'] = DCF_AFTER_UPDATE.duplicated(subset=['dcf_ide'],keep='last')
        DCF_AFTER_UPDATE['dcf_status'] = DCF_AFTER_UPDATE.apply(lambda row: 2 if row['duplicate'] else row['dcf_status'],axis=1)
        DCF_AFTER_UPDATE = DCF_AFTER_UPDATE.drop_duplicates(subset=['dcf_ide'],keep='first').drop(columns=['duplicate'])      
        DCF_AFTER_UPDATE = DCF_AFTER_UPDATE.drop(['DEF'], axis=1)
        DCF_AFTER_UPDATE.rename(columns = {'pat':'patient',}, inplace = True)
        # Cast date into string format to be able to dumps data
        DCF_AFTER_UPDATE = DCF_AFTER_UPDATE.astype({'record_date': str}) if not DCF_AFTER_UPDATE.empty else DCF_AFTER_UPDATE


        records = DCF_AFTER_UPDATE.to_dict(orient='records')
        
        for record in records:
            DataCorrectionForm.objects.update_or_create(
                dcf_ide=record['dcf_ide'], # filter to search for existing objects => should not be pass to default (if not IntegrityError)
                defaults = {
                    'category':record['category'],
                    'crf':record['crf'],
                    'crf_ide':record['crf_ide'],
                    'patient':record['patient'],
                    'record_date':record['record_date'],
                    'field_name':record['field_name'],
                    'field_label':record['field_label'],
                    'message':record['message'],
                    'field_value':record['field_value'],
                    'dcf_status':record['dcf_status'],
                    'created_date':record['created_date'],
                    # 'DEF':record['DEF'],
                    'deactivated':record['deactivated'],
                    'comments':record['comments']
                }
            )

    Log.objects.create(dcf_edition_status=1)
    
    return True
```

---

**EDIT 2022-10-03 17:00**

in fact reading CAVEATS:

> The development server creates a new thread for each request it
> handles, negating the effect of persistent connections. Don’t enable
> them during development.

---

**EDIT 2022-10-03 16:00**

Django 2.2.5

I have tried to set DATABASES parameter CONN_MAX_AGE as per Django documentation but it doesn't change anythings

> Default: 0
>
> The lifetime of a database connection, as an integer of seconds. Use 0
> to close database connections at the end of each request — Django’s
> historical behavior — and None for unlimited persistent connections.

---

I use Celery task and got an error I do not understand.

I loop over a table (that contain query definitions) to edit missing/inconsistent data in a database (using API) and registered discrepencies in another table.

If I run query one at a time, it works but when I try to loop over queries, I got an error

`OperationalError('server closed the connection unexpectedly\n\tThis probably means the server terminated abnormally\n\tbefore or while processing the request.\n')`

```
def DCF_edition(self):

    DCF_BEFORE_UPDATE = pd.DataFrame.from_records(DataCorrectionForm.objects.all().values())
    DCF_BEFORE_UPDATE = DCF_BEFORE_UPDATE.astype({'record_date': str,'created_date': str}) if not DCF_BEFORE_UPDATE.empty else DCF_BEFORE_UPDATE

    data = []
    # load queries definition
    queries = queries_definitions()
    if not queries.empty:
        for index, row in queries.iterrows():
           
            try:
                missing_or_inconsistent =  missing_or_inconsistent_data(row['ide'],row['query_type'],row['crf_name'].lower(),row['crf identification 
                data.append(missing_or_inconsistent[['dcf_ide','category','crf','crf_ide','pat','record_date','field_name','field_label','message','field_value','dcf_status','DEF','deactivated']])

                DCF_AFTER_UPDATE = pd.concat(data)
                DCF_AFTER_UPDATE = DCF_AFTER_UPDATE.drop_duplicates(keep='last')

                DCF_AFTER_UPDATE = DCF_AFTER_UPDATE.drop(['DEF'], axis=1)
                DCF_AFTER_UPDATE.rename(columns = {'pat':'patient',}, inplace = True)

            except Exception as e:
                Log.objects.create(dcf_edition_status=0,dcf_edition_exception=str(e)[:200])
                continue

        # Cast date into string format to be able to dumps data
        DCF_AFTER_UPDATE = DCF_AFTER_UPDATE.astype({'record_date': str}) if not DCF_AFTER_UPDATE.empty else DCF_AFTER_UPDATE
    
        records = json.loads(json.dumps(list(DCF_AFTER_UPDATE.T.to_dict().values())))
        for record in records:
            if not DCF_BEFORE_UPDATE.empty and record['dcf_ide'] in DCF_BEFORE_UPDATE.values:
                DataCorrectionForm.objects.filter(dcf_ide=record['dcf_ide']).update(dcf_status=2)
            else:
                DataCorrectionForm.objects.get_or_create(**record)
    
        # resolved dcf => status=0
        if not DCF_BEFORE_UPDATE.empty:
            records = json.loads(json.dumps(list(DCF_BEFORE_UPDATE.T.to_dict().values())))
            for record in records:
                if record['dcf_ide'] not in DCF_AFTER_UPDATE.values:
                    DataCorrectionForm.objects.filter(dcf_ide=record['dcf_ide']).update(dcf_status=0)
    
    Log.objects.create(dcf_edition_status=1)
    
    return True
```

Comment: Did you inspect the error logs of your database server to check for any error that would have caused the connection to shut down unexpectedly?

Comment: I guess this is due to low memory of system, or high memory usages. Just a guess work.

Answer (score 0):

> The lifetime of a database connection, as an integer of seconds. Use 0 to close database connections at the end of each request — Django’s historical behavior — and None for unlimited persistent connections.

It seems that your task is long running task and need to hold the db connection for a long period. Did you try to set it to None

```
DATABASES = {
'default': env.db(),
}
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#conn-max-age
DATABASES['default']['CONN_MAX_AGE'] = None
```

How long does your task need to finish? It could be another problem with server database setting, ex `tcp_keepalives_ilde`..

Comment: CONN_MAX_AGE has no effect with Django runserver... the task long about 1:15 to complete. To date, I have seperate my initial task in 2 tasks, the first create a cvs file use by the second task... but it is just a hack for the moment